# Smarty PHP, AbanteCart E-Commerce User Agent Theme

Tags: php, web, open-source, e-commerce, smarty

I've been using the open source AbanteCart E-Commerce for selling productus and was wondering if someone knew there was a way to redirect the template for use of a mobile template instead.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the easiest way is hook of all controllers and adding new variable into request (sf) which contains template_text_id... plus using cookie about template mode(desktop or mobile).

```
 /**
 * redirect to mobile template if we load page in mobile device
 **/
public function onAHook_InitEnd() {
    if ( $this->_processHooks() ) return;
    $device = $this->baseObject->request->getDeviceType();
    if ( !empty($device) && empty( $this->baseObject->request->cookie['abantecart_mobile_redirect'] ) ) {
        //set flag that redirect was done
        setcookie("abantecart_mobile_redirect", "1", time() + 3600*24);
        //set template to mobile
        $url = $this->baseObject->html->removeQueryVar($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'sf');
        $url .= '&sf=your_mobile_template_text_id';
        header ( 'Location: '. $url );
    }
}
private function _processHooks(){
        return $this->registry->get('config')->get('config_storefront_template') == 'your_mobile_template_text_id';
    }
```

That variable (sf) processed by engine in core/init.php file and switch desktop template to mobile.